# Getting bottlenecked using graph edit distance for networkx graphs. Any good alternatives?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am currently getting bottlenecked using graph edit distance for networkx graphs. My code currently looks like this (I am appending 50 pairwise graph analysis results to a list of dictionaries).

```
lst_of_dct = []
for i in range(len(pair_list)):
    dict = {}
    # extract edges values for graphs 1 & 2
    edge_1 = [list(e) for e in pair_list[i][0].edges]
    edge_2 = [list(e) for e in pair_list[i][1].edges]
    dict["my_graph1"] = edge_1
    dict["my_graph2"] = edge_2
    node1 = pair_list[i][0].nodes
    node2 = pair_list[i][1].nodes
    dict["labels_1"] = node1
    dict["labels_2"] = node2
    for v in nx.optimize_graph_edit_distance(pair_list[i][0], pair_list[i][1]):
        ged = v
    #ged = nx.graph_edit_distance(pair_list[i][0], pair_list[i][1])
    dict["ged"] = ged
    lst_of_dct.append(dict)
    print('1')
```

After about 3 iterations of my for loop, it just gets stuck calculating the fourth GED. I calculated the GED individually on a scratch sheet to see how long it takes without the for loop, and the graph pair for the fourth iteration only takes ~3 seconds. I was just wondering why am I getting bottlenecked at the fourth iteration if it only takes ~3 seconds to calculate without a for loop?

I guess this really isn't a what have I tried problem. Just a matter of why is this happening? Things I could try but would be kind of annoying would be to iterate 5 for loops at a time... which would result in 20 different for loops appending the same dictionary again and again. I think this is not a great idea, but this could be a last result if it comes down to it. I could just hard-code it in, but I would rather not have to do this because I am expected to do this same procedure for a much larger dataset in the future.

Comment: can you add example for `pair_list`

Comment: I was dumb. It turns out that the fourth iteration was bottlenecking. I am currently looking for alternative ways to collecting the GED values. I might just alternatively force a pass to the next iteration if it takes longer than ~1 minute or something if all GED calculations are just too computationally intractable.